# How to install my Plugin programmatically to Lotus Notes?

Tags: java, plugins, installation, lotus-notes

I have recently successfully developed a lotus notes plugin using java which monitors mails. The plugin is working fine if I am installing it to my lotus notes using update site and feature plugin manually. How can I install this plugin silently/programmatically to my lotus notes? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no open documented API to implement this functionality using java on Lotus Notes Client.

Consider platform dependent automation tools, like Windows Script and/or AutoIt.

Save all actions to a script file and distribute this script along with your plugin. Provide end-users with instruction, how to run this script to install your plugin.